# How to put size to column

Tags: flutter

I am a beginner in flutter, I want to create a column that takes up all the screen space, please tell me how to do it ?

What i expected to happen : column that occupies the entire screen space

Comment: Can you include your current snippet

Comment: Please, show your current code implementations, a expected screenshot or similar.

Comment: a snippet of code you tried will be helpful

Comment: always ask question with your tried code....none will give u brand new code

Answer (score 0):

Inside the column you can use container where you can wrap that one with expanded which will expand the whole space available to it